# Why JSON return value has "\" in it on production but not on staging?

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf

I have a function running on the same Staging site & Production site, on staging the WCF returns a JSON result just like normal while I watch it in browser debugger, and JSON.parse(result) is OK. But on production, the same environment setting and function, the WCF returns a JSON with "\", more or less like a string, so JSON.parse(result) throw out error, invalid character or JSON.parse: bad escaped character.

Example:
ON staging JSON format is good, and could be parsed as JSON data type.
But on production it looks like this:

```
{ "d" : [{"type": "SearchFilterModel.LookupSearchListItem", "base_where_clause": " (1 = 1)  and (last_name like \'%Yes%\') ", "filters": "[{\"operator\":[{\"OperatorId\":1,\"DisplayName\":\"Contains\",\"SqlName\":\"like\"}] }]}
```

As you could see there are "\" been inserted into the JSON data source, but not on staging. 
Does anyone know why under the same IIS6 server but generate two different results for JSON?

Comment: Can you post the actual function?

Comment: also if can share sample json from both environments

Comment: @BradM  I used backbone, and it calls a web service's method to return data back with JSON format. The thing is the same function and data work fine on staging and some other projects, but only not working correctly on one production environment, which the web service returns result with JSON format with "\" in it...

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh I posted the production JSON, and the staging JSON data is the same without "\". it's an example.

Comment: And I am thinking if there is any server side configuration which made the difference.